# undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, LZespolona&)'

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, istream, ostream

I got two error messages when I try create LZespolona type Wektor:

```
undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, LZespolona&)'|
undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, LZespolona const&)'
```

When I create `Wektor<double>` everything is fine, but when I try to create `Wektor` of my abstract type `<LZespolona>`, something's wrong. I guess its related to incorrect implementation of operator-overloading for LZespolona.
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Wektor.hh"
#include "lzespolona.hh"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Wektor<LZespolona> W; //When it's `Wektor<double> W` everything works fine
    cin >> W;
}
```

Wektor.hh:

```
#include "rozmiar.h"
#include "lzespolona.hh"
#include <iostream>

template<typename typ>
class Wektor
{

    typ tabwektor[ROZMIAR];

public:
    typ  operator [] (int  xyz) const {return tabwektor[xyz];}
    typ& operator [] (int  xyz) {return tabwektor[xyz];}
};

template<typename typ>
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &Strm, Wektor<typ> &Wek)
{
    for (int i=0; i<ROZMIAR; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> Wek[i];//undefined reference to `operator>>(std::istream&, LZespolona&)'|
    }
    return Strm;
}

template<typename typ>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &Strm,  Wektor<typ> &Wek)
{
    for (int i=0; i<ROZMIAR; i++)
    {
        std::cout << Wek[i]<<" "; //undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, LZespolona const&)'
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return Strm;
}
```

Part of LZespolona.hh:

```
std::ostream&  operator << ( std::ostream&      StrmWy,
                             const LZespolona&  WyswietlanaLiczba
std::istream&  operator >> ( std::istream&StrmWe, LZespolona &zespolona) ;
```

LZespolona.cpp:

```
std::ostream&  operator << ( std::ostream&      StrmWy,
                             const LZespolona&  WyswietlanaLiczba)
{
    std::cout<< WyswietlanaLiczba.Re();
    if(WyswietlanaLiczba.Im() < 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"+";
    }

    std::cout << WyswietlanaLiczba.Im() << "i" << "  ";
    return StrmWy;
}

istream&operator >> (istream&StrmWe, LZespolona &zespolona)
{
    char Znak;
    cin.get();
    StrmWe >> zespolona.Re();
    StrmWe >> Znak;

    if(Znak == '+')
    {
        StrmWe >> zespolona.Im();
    }

    if(Znak == '-')
    {
        StrmWe.putback(Znak);
        StrmWe >> zespolona.Im();
    }
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return StrmWe;
}
```

Comment: Do you ever define that function?

Comment: I see declarations of stream operators in `LZespolona.h`, but where are the definitions?

Comment: I've got the definitions in LZespolona.cpp, I'll update op.

Comment: How are you compiling the program?

Comment: "How are you compiling the program?" ok, it was good question, CodeBlocks(GNU GCC) caused the problem. When I've created my own makefile, everything worked fine. Problem solved :)

Comment: @user3231776 Could you post the specifics of your solution as an answer? I'm curious to see what fixed it. :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 I've created my own makefile instead of using the one in Code::Blocks, heres my Makefile
`CPPFLAGS= -c -g -Iinc -Wall -pedantic  
  
__start__: uklad_rownan  
 ./uklad_rownan  
  
uklad_rownan: main.o lzespolona.o  
 g++ -Wall -pedantic -o uklad_rownan main.o lzespolona.o  
  
main.o: main.cpp Wektor.hh lzespolona.hh rozmiar.h  
 g++ ${CPPFLAGS} -o main.o main.cpp  
  
lzespolona.o: lzespolona.cpp lzespolona.hh   
 g++ ${CPPFLAGS} -o lzespolona.o lzespolona.cpp  

clean:  
 rm -f *.o uklad_rownan  
`

Also I used GCC 4.8.2 instead of 4.8.1